# S4cmd giving permission denied error

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, s3cmd

I installed S4cmd on my Ec2 Ubuntu instance, but when trying to run it was giving this below

> error:-bash: /usr/local/bin/s4cmd: Permission denied

I tried everything like sudo -s, updating pip & everything advised in other questions. But none of them working for me.

As of now, I am using S3cmd. But the PUT requests from EC2 to either DreamObjects or to CenturyLink Object Storage are painfully slow. It was uploading one-by-one. My project demands uploading an extremely large number (over a million) of very small objects.

Answer (score 3):

This quite possibly is not a useful answer, but are you trying to execute the file when it doesn't have permission to be an executable. Go to the `/usr/local/bin/` directory and try the following command

```
chmod +x s4cmd
```

and see if that works...

Comment: PS http://superuser.com/ might be a better place to ask this question...

Comment: But s4cmd seems to be working only for Amazon s3, not for other object storage services. I just asked this on superuser [link](http://superuser.com/questions/1161907/s4cmd-working-only-for-amazon-s3-how-to-configure-it-for-dreamobjects-cloud-sto). Could you please help for that too.

Comment: The above was the limit of my knowledge, I am afraid. I have never used s4cmd or s3cmd, but I recognised the error message, so could guess at the solution. I have nothing more to add than the answer you got. Sorry!!!